# precise dimensions of mesh components

Tags: plotting

```
CA = CellularAutomaton[22, {{1}, 0}, 50];
ListPlot3D[CA, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

I'm trying to set the exact dimensions of the "mesh rectangles" here. They look like they're about 2:1 ... how do I set the dimensions exactly? Thanks!

[image]

P.S. I don't know the precise term for these "mesh components"... I'll update the wording of the question if someone can tell me what they are called.

Comment: They look like they are square. The problem is that the axes of the plot have different ranges, you can try to see what happens if you add `BoxRatios->Automatic`. But I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem here. [`DiscretePlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot3D.html) is better suited for your situation than `ListPlot3D`.

Comment: You can also try this: `Show[
 Graphics3D[],
 ListPlot3D[CA, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
 ]`. `Graphics3D` are always depicted isometrically, and `Show` will grab the plotting options from its first argument.